# Styling up hidden input

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to style up a hidden input field, but I'm not getting it quite right.

It may sound strange trying to style up an input box that's hidden - reason being is that the text in those fields are shown upon clicking the submit button, and I'd like to change the font and colour so it matches the rest of the page.

Code below (I have just removed the company details in URLs)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base-asbestos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive-widths.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive-layout-asbestos.css">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function updateAuthor(theForm) {
            if (theForm.extensionField_Name) {
                if (theForm.extensionField_Name.value != "") {
                    theForm.author.value = theForm.extensionField_Name.value;
                    theForm.extensionField_Name.name = 'extensionField_h_Name';
                    return (true);
                }
            }
            if (theForm.extensionField_Email) {
                if (theForm.extensionField_Email.value != "") {
                    theForm.author.value = theForm.extensionField_Email.value;
                    theForm.extensionField_Email.name = 'extensionField_h_Email';
                    return (true);
                }
            }
            return (true);
        }
    </script>

    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style type="text/css">
        .chat {
            color: #404040;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
        }


        input[type=submit] {
            color: #404040;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 0.95em;
            font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
        }

        chat2 {
            color: #25ab9a;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 0.95em;
            font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="intenal standard_colours" style="position: relative;  top: 0;">
    <div class="chat">

        <form action="https://test.uk/ccp/chat/form/100000" method="post" onsubmit="return updateAuthor(this)">
            <style type="text/css">
                span {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 120px;
                }
            </style>
            <span>Name:</span><input type="text" name="extensionField_Name" /><br /><br>
            <span>Email:</span><input type="text" name="extensionField_Email" /><br />            <br>
            <span>Phone number:</span><input type="text" name="extensionField_PhoneNumber" /><br /><br>
            <span>Category:</span>
            <select name="extensionField_ccxqueuetag">
                <br />
                <option value="Chat_Csq7">General</option>
            </select><br><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><input type="hidden" name="author" value="Customer" /><br />

            <input type="hidden" name="title" value="ccx chat" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_h_widgetName" value="ChatGeneral" /><br />
            <!-- The following optional, hidden fields are available in order to customize the Customer Chat user interface.
            Unlike other extension fields, these are not added to the social contact, and therefore do not display in the Agent Chat user interface.-->
            <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatLogo" value="https://tes.t/blank.jpg"><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatWaiting" value="Welcome.         Please wait while we connect you to a customer care representative.">
            <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatAgentJoinTimeOut" value="All customer care representatives are busy. Please wait or try again later.">
            <input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatError" value="Sorry, the chat service is currently not available. Please try again later.">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are doing this an unusual way. The use of input fields for that purpose is not semantically correct. I would use javascript or flashdata to add the messages you need inside the correct HTML tags. If you insist on using input fields, then try using text fields, not hidden fields, and use CSS to hide them.

Comment: Instead use `input` with class 'hidden' and hide it using `style="display: none"`. Later you can make it visible by setting it back to `style="display:initial"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class:

```
.Hidden{
display:none;
}
```

and you can call this class for all objects that you need to hide.

Comment: .Show{display:initial;}

Answer (score 0):

Instead use normal text box with class "**hidden**" having style `display: none`. This will hide the text box.

You can make it visible by setting `display` back to `initial` using JavaScript like

```
document.getElementsByName('author')[0].style.display = 'initial';
```

---

**Snippet:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base-asbestos.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive-widths.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive-layout-asbestos.css">
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function updateAuthor(theForm) {

      /* Use this code to display the element */
      document.getElementsByName('author')[0].style.display = 'initial';


      if (theForm.extensionField_Name) {
        if (theForm.extensionField_Name.value != "") {
          theForm.author.value = theForm.extensionField_Name.value;
          theForm.extensionField_Name.name = 'extensionField_h_Name';
          return (true);
        }
      }
      if (theForm.extensionField_Email) {
        if (theForm.extensionField_Email.value != "") {
          theForm.author.value = theForm.extensionField_Email.value;
          theForm.extensionField_Email.name = 'extensionField_h_Email';
          return (true);
        }
      }
      return (true);
    }
  </script>

  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style type="text/css">
    .chat {
      color: #404040;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
      color: #404040;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 0.95em;
      font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    }
    chat2 {
      color: #25ab9a;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 0.95em;
      font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    }
    /* Use this to hide the input text box */
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="intenal standard_colours" style="position: relative;  top: 0;">
  <div class="chat">

    <form action="https://test.uk/ccp/chat/form/100000" method="post" onSubmit="return updateAuthor(this)">
      <style type="text/css">
        span {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 120px;
        }
      </style>
      <span>Name:</span>
      <input type="text" name="extensionField_Name" />
      <br/>
      <br>
      <span>Email:</span>
      <input type="text" name="extensionField_Email" />
      <br/>
      <br>
      <span>Phone number:</span>
      <input type="text" name="extensionField_PhoneNumber" />
      <br/>
      <br>
      <span>Category:</span>
      <select name="extensionField_ccxqueuetag">
        <br/>
        <option value="Chat_Csq7">General</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input type="text" class="hidden" name="author" value="Customer" />
      <br/>

      <input type="text" class="hidden" name="title" value="ccx chat" />
      <br/>
      <input type="text" class="hidden" name="extensionField_h_widgetName" value="ChatGeneral" />
      <br/>
      <!-- The following optional, hidden fields are available in order to customize the Customer Chat user interface.
Unlike other extension fields, these are not added to the social contact, and therefore do not display in the Agent Chat user interface.-->
      <input type="text" class="hidden" name="extensionField_chatLogo" value="https://tes.t/blank.jpg">
      <br/>
      <input type="text" class="hidden" name="extensionField_chatWaiting" value="Welcome.         Please wait while we connect you to a customer care representative.">
      <input type="text" class="hidden" name="extensionField_chatAgentJoinTimeOut" value="All customer care representatives are busy. Please wait or try again later.">
      <input type="text" class="hidden" name="extensionField_chatError" value="Sorry, the chat service is currently not available. Please try again later.">
  </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this almost works, but for some reason the styling of the content that upon clicking the submit button (i.e. Welcome. Please wait while we connect you to a customer care representative.") doesn't seem to get pulled through and is still displayed in a different font?

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a class to those hidden inputs (let's call it "**hiddenField**")

2) Add whatever styles like this

```
.hiddenField{
 font-color:red;
 font-size:12px;
}
```

3) Call something this to make them visible

```
if(document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('type') == 'hidden') {
   document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('type', 'text');
}
```